# Sample XML and Generated Classes derived from XSD don't match

Tags: xml, visual-studio-2013, xsd, xsd.exe

Based on an **XSD** file, I have first **generated a sample XML** file and next via menu-option  *Copy/PasteSpecial* "Paste XML as Classes" **generated the Classes** that would match with the generated XML. Seems to me like a roundtrip.

DOing the analog operations from the VS commandprompt gives slightly different classes, but with the same result:
**When Deserializing this XML back into the generated classes, I cannot get rid of the "XML error on (0,0)"  or "root element is missing".**

The working environment for this question is Visual Studio 2013.4.

What is happening here?

[This  is the XSD](https://www.istandaarden.nl/bep/iWlz10/html/AW33.xsd) where it all starts.

The XSD is provided to me from an external party, so I have no infuence on it's content.